# Microservices architecture for survey

Tags: microservices

Is a microservices architecture a good approach for developing a survey 
application with the following features:

- survey creation
- online or offline data collecting
- Reporting

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)** "If your question... is just a copy paste of homework problem, expect it to be downvoted, closed, and deleted - potentially in quite short order."

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable.  Architectures address *non-functional requirements* like scalability, maintainability and performance, not functional requirements like survey creation or data collection.  A good architecture should be able to satisfy *any* business domain.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Microservices are a possible solution to various problems. Unless you have these problems, don't use them. For example:

- There are different teams that have to develop and deploy their components separately (compare [Conway's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_law)). If the components can be deployed together, a monolith may be simpler.
- You have to horizontally scale different parts of an application separately. If you do not want to scale horizontally or if all parts of the application can be scaled together, a monolith may be simpler.

By using microservices, you are creating a distributed system. Those are massively more complex than non-distributed systems. You don't want that complexity unless other problems are *even worse*.

Comment: Funny how we now call the traditional approach a "monolith," a word that already has negative connotations in software engineering circles.